# scala read file,and each line save to a variable?

Tags: scala

scalaresult.txt

```
0~250::250~500::500~750::750~1000::1000~1250
481::827::750::256::1000
```

scala code

```
 val filename = "/home/user/scalaresult.txt"
 for ( (line,index) <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines().zipWithIndex){ 
  println(line)
  println(index)
 }

 //val step_x = "0~250::250~500::500~750::750~1000::1000~1250"
 //val step_y = "481::827::750::256::1000"
Seq("java", "-jar", "/home/user/birt2.jar" , step_x , step_y , "BarChart").lines
```

I have a file: scalaresult.txt

I need to save first line `(index(0))` to  step_x 
and the second line `(index(1))` to  step_y

How to do this ? Please guide me Thank you.

Comment: what does it have to do with apache-spark?

Comment: sorry,I edit it. I just thought maybe it can use spark rdd.still not familiar with these skills.

Comment: And what if you have 1 millions lines? You'll create a Val for each line?

Comment: in this case,just 2 variables. Or What's the better way to do this? Please teach me

Comment: Can you try to explain what are you trying to achieve from a functional point of view? It's not very clear what you are trying to do!

Comment: I have to get 2 variables(step_x and step_y) Because I need x and y for BIRT to draw picture.  so I need to get the result ````val step_x = "0~250::250~500::500~750::750~1000::1000~1250"```` and ````val step_y = "481::827::750::256::1000"````   But I have know idea how to do this after I read the file ````scalaresult.txt````

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76143/discussion-between-eliasah-and-user2492364).

Comment: What is the `.lines` method on `Seq` supposed to do. It's not part of the standard `Seq` class

Answer (score 4):

This is not the optimal solution, but you can try the following: (I'm not a scala expert yet! :P)

```
scala> val it = Source.fromFile(filename).getLines().toList
it: List[String] = List(0~250::250~500::500~750::750~1000::1000~1250, "481::827::750::256::1000 ")

scala> it(1)
res7: String = "481::827::750::256::1000 "

scala> it(0)
res8: String = 0~250::250~500::500~750::750~1000::1000~1250
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you are trying to do it take the two lines from the file and inserting them into the sequence, the indexer on the list will do the trick. Mind you, it's an O(n) operation on list, so if there were a lot of lines, it wouldn't be the best approach.

```
val filename = "/home/user/scalaresult.txt"
val lines = Source.fromFile(filename).getLines()
val seq = Seq("java", "-jar", "/home/user/birt2.jar" , lines(0) , lines(1), "BarChart")
```